# Use the same dll between many .net core 3 windows forms applications like GAC

Tags: winforms, deployment, .net-core-3.0

I have many application that use the same dlls (like System.Data.SqlClient).
I publish the applications framework dependent and single file. 
I'm looking for a way to not include in all the exe this common dlls

I've tried to search how to create a custom .net core runtime installer (like .NET Core Desktop Installer) for install the dlls in the dotnet folder without success.

The nearest solution that I have found is the [Runtime package store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store) but seems to not working without installing the .net core sdk in the clients

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is a good example for *avoiding* this - it's already being replaced by `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`. Different applications, especially those that use EF Core 3, will want to use different versions of the package

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have see that in the dotnet folder there are many version of the same dll so I think it's possible to have different applications with different versions